# BDD behave Python need to create a World map to hold values

Tags: python, bdd, suds, python-behave

I'm not too familiar with Python but I have setup a BDD framework using Python behave, I now want to create a World map class that holds data and is retrievable throughout all scenarios.

For instance I will have a world class where I can use:

```
World w 

w.key.add('key', api.response)
```

In one scenario and in another I can then use:

```
World w

key = w.key.get('key').
```

Edit:

Or if there is a built in way of using context or similar in behave where the attributes are saved and retrievable throughout all scenarios that would be good.

Like lettuce where you can use world http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html

I've tried this between scenarios but it doesn't seem to be picking it up

```
class World(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.__dict__[key] = item
        print(item)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
```

Setting the item in one step in scenario A: w.**setitem**('key', response)

Getting the item in another step in scenario B: w.**getitem**('key',)

This shows me an error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1456, in run
    match.run(runner.context)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1903, in run
    self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "steps\get_account.py", line 14, in step_impl
    print(w.__getitem__('appToken'))
  File "C:Project\steps\world.py", line 8, in __getitem__
    return self.__dict__[key]
KeyError: 'key'
```

It appears that the World does not hold values here between steps that are run.

Edit:

I'm unsure how to use environment.py but can see it has a way of running code before the steps. How can I allow my call to a soap client within environment.py to be called and then pass this to a particular step?

Edit:

I have made the request in environment.py and hardcoded the values, how can I pass variables to environment.py and back?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this I actually used a config file [config.py] I then added the variables in there and retrieved them using getattr. See below:

```
WSDL_URL = 'wsdl'
USERNAME = 'name'
PASSWORD = 'PWD'
```

Then retrieved them like:

```
import config

getattr(config, 'USERNAME ', 'username not found')
```

Comment: This might be a valid solution for your specific case but does not answer your own question on how to share data between scenarios. Stovfl's answer has the best suggestion to that question, using global variables.

Comment: This is not true because I can also modify the values in the configuration and retrieve them easily. To me this is easier than using global variables

Comment: The big difference is that your step definitions can not as easily modify the config.py as they could modify a global variable. Of course in your case you don't need to modify it, that's why it's a special case of sharing data between scenarios, and not what the original question was about, which was writing to an instance of the world class in one scenario and read the token back in another.

Comment: So they can't modify the configuration with setattr?

Comment: Actually you are right, you can, in memory. It will just not be persisted. I expected behave to delete the imports between scenarios but it doesn't, I just tried. Oh, and you can simply use config.USERNAME instead of getattr and setattr.

Answer (score 4):

It's called "context" in the python-behave jargon. The first argument of your step definition function is an instance of the behave.runner.Context class, in which you can store your world instance. Please see [the appropriate part of the tutorial.](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#context)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't share the context between scenarios which is what I need. As I'm using a soap client I need to take the key to the next scenario

Comment: Yes, that's right, the context in re-created for each scenario in order to minimize possible interference between scenarios. You must not rely on any order of execution for your scenarios. If you really insist on sharing data between scenarios, you could persist your data on disk and re-read it from there, but your next problem is most likely going to be that your scenarios will sometimes execute in an unexpected order.
You should rather construct you scenarios in a way that you aquire a new key in each scenario that needs it. Either using tags+beforescenario or a dedicated step definition.

Comment: Is there a way to run a call to a soap client and retrieve the token and pass it to a particular step inside environment.py?

Comment: You don't call methods of environment.py directly. You can define before_all and before_scenario hooks just as stovfl suggests. 
As to when to request the soap token, it's entirely up to you. You can use the same token for the entire test run for all scenarios if you keep it in a global variable or you can re-request if for every scenario and just store it in the context and you might as well re-request it for every single request whenever you need it. It really depends on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the 
simple approach, using `global var`, for instance:

```
def before_all(context):
    global response
    response = api.response

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    global response
    w.key.add('key', response)
```

---

Guess `feature` can be accessed from `context`, for instance:

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    feature.response = api.response

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    w.key.add('key', context.feature.response)
```

---

You are looking for:
**Class variable**: A variable that is shared by all instances of a class.
Your code in Q uses *Class Instance variable*.
Read about: [python_classes_objects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

For instance:

```
class World(dict):
    __class_var = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        World.__class_var[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return World.__class_var[key]

# Scenario A
A = World()
A['key'] = 'test'
print('A[\'key\']=%s' % A['key'] )
del A

# Scenario B
B = World()
print('B[\'key\']=%s' % B['key'] )
```

**Output**:

```
A['key']=test
B['key']=test
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***
Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.

Comment: This doesn't work as the ordering of tests aren't run in the right order. I have added this to environment.py but need to know how to pass variables to this

Comment: No I mean something like this https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/environment.py

Comment: @stovi thanks for your help but what I actually want it to be able to pass a variable from a class.py file which is in BDD steps to the environment.py which is in the project folder location. Then use these variables to make a request. Then pass the response back to class.py. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Samantha: Have you tried any of the `def before_...` proposals?

Answer (score 1):

Defining `global var` in before_all hook did not work for me.
As mentioned by @stovfl

But defining global var within one of my steps worked out.

Instead, as Szabo Peter mentioned use the context.

`context.your_variable_name = api.response`
and just use 
`context.your_variable_name` anywhere the value is to be used.